# Axios: returns 404 when making POST request

Tags: node.js, axios

I am new with nodejs and axios. I am working on making the login work as of the moment, but Axios is giving me a `404 not found` error whenever I call it inside my controller.

This is how I am doing it. I'm pretty sure I am using axios correctly. I don't have any idea as to why it is giving 404 error.

```
app.post('/post-login', urlencodeParser, async function (req, res) {
    const instance = axios.create();
    req.body.grant_type = "password";
    req.body.client_id = null;
    req.body.client_secret = null;
    
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    try{
      const response = await instance.post(jsonData.baseURL+'/auth/login',JSON.stringify(req.body),{headers:headers});
      res.status(200).json(response);
      console.log(response);
    }catch(e){
      res.status(500).json({ message: e });
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

this is what I get when testing the API endpoint in postman
[image: postman data]

and this is the headers
[image: headers]

Comment: Well, 404 means the request was sent and the server returned 404 (not found).
It could mean that you're calling an endpoint that does not exist or trying to get a resource that does not exist. Have you tried calling /auth/login outside of your controller ?

Comment: yeah, the API endpoint is working on postman I can confirm that I am calling the same API endpoint. but here on my code it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you're using json encoded data (by using json.stringify) and sending it using the 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content type.
I would advise you to pass the body without encoding it.
Like this:

```
app.post('/post-login', urlencodeParser, async function (req, res) {
    const instance = axios.create();
    req.body.grant_type = "password";
    req.body.client_id = null;
    req.body.client_secret = null;
    
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    try{
      const response = await instance.post(jsonData.baseURL+'/auth/login', req.body,{headers:headers});
      res.status(200).json(response);
      console.log(response);
    }catch(e){
      res.status(500).json({ message: e });
    }
});
```

[More on why you should not pass an encoded json to axis with form content-type](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/post-json)

Comment: I actually already tried that, but it is still returning 404 response

Comment: Weird, could you show what you're sending with Postman ? There might be an extra parameter or header that's missing

Comment: there you go, I updated the post and include screenshots with postman

Comment: Thank you,
Only problem I could see is maybe the username and password fields aren't passed well, you could check if req.body has the right field with the right field names (if you haven't already checked them)
And if that still does not work, you can try using the export request feature in postman, which basically generates axios code (if you set it to js) and compare with yours

Comment: it's really weird. I tried the generated code from postman, that one also gives 404 error..

Answer (score 0):

For people coming from Search Engines like me, if you are using a singleton patttern for accesing an axios instance i.e:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const dataAPI = axios.create();

export default dataAPI;
```

make sure your Axios instance is not getting modified by an `axios-mock-adapter`.
If so, call `adapter.restore()` to get back to initial state.

> Note: there's a difference between `.restore()` and `.reset()`

Quoting from [docs](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#example)

> You can restore the original adapter (which will remove the mocking behavior)
>
> `mock.restore();`
>
> You can also reset the registered mock handlers with resetHandlers
>
> `mock.resetHandlers();`
>
> You can reset both registered mock handlers and history items with reset
>
> `mock.reset();`

Answer (score 0):

For the Typescript people who reached this question from search engines:

Make sure to frame http header values in quotes. 
 Node's HTTPS request will accept headers without quotes for boolean and numbers, but axios accepts only if the value is surrounded with quotes. So headers will not be passed along with the request in case of axios if we use same headers which we use for https/http in axios.

Non-Working sample:

```
const config = {
        headers: {'x-mock-match-request-body':false, 'x-mock-match-request-headers':false}
      };
      const response = await axios.post(requestUrl, null, config);
```

Working sample:

```
const config = {
        headers: {'x-mock-match-request-body':'false', 'x-mock-match-request-headers':'false'}
      };
      const response = await axios.post(requestUrl, null, config);
```